# HMS 3D Modeling Kit, Motion Capture feature getting crash

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

In the 3D Modeling Kit GitHub code, Motion Capture feature getting crash.

https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-3d-modeling-demo

Step 1 : Run the GitHub  project

Step 2 : Click on Motion Capture

Step 3 : Click on either Live or Video or Photo option

````
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.huawei.hms.motioncapturesdk.SkeletonDetectionJNI.createInstance(android.content.res.AssetManager, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_huawei_hms_motioncapturesdk_SkeletonDetectionJNI_createInstance and Java_com_huawei_hms_motioncapturesdk_SkeletonDetectionJNI_createInstance__Landroid_content_res_AssetManager_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
       at com.huawei.hms.motioncapturesdk.SkeletonDetectionJNI.createInstance(Native Method)
       at com.huawei.hms.motioncapturesdk.a.initialize(ImageSkeletonImpl.java:12)
       at com.huawei.hms.motioncapturesdk.t.b.a(RemoteOnDeviceSkeleton.java:14)
       at com.huawei.hms.motioncapturesdk.Modeling3dMotionCaptureEngine.create(Modeling3dMotionCaptureEngine.java:13)
       at com.huawei.hms.motioncapturesdk.Modeling3dMotionCaptureEngineFactory.getMotionCaptureEngine(Modeling3dMotionCaptureEngineFactory.java:1)
       at com.huawei.hms.modeling3d.utils.skeleton.LocalSkeletonProcessor.<init>(LocalSkeletonProcessor.java:67)
       at com.huawei.hms.modeling3d.ui.activity.SelectSourceVideoActivity.onCreate(SelectSourceVideoActivity.java:101)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Motion Capture only supports armv8 architecture devices. This capability requires a 64-bit ARM-based Android phone.

For details , refer to [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/graphics-Guides/faq-0000001111559676):

Refer [this link](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/) for ARMv8 architecture device list.